# How do i localize the app name of a air ios app?

Tags: ios, air

I am trying to compile an adobe air app for iOS with Danish app name? 
I can get localization to work with eg English, French and German, but not with Danish...

The problem is that the app name on the dashboard changes between english, french or german according to the language selection under ios settings, but when i select danish under settings the app name does not display the danish name.

I put

```
<name>
  <text xml:lang="en"> English </ text>
  <text xml:lang="da"> and Danish </ text>
</name>
```

in the app.xml before i compile with the adt, but after compile i can see that only the English name is created in the InfoPlist.strings of the ipa.

Any ideas on how to achieve a localized app name

Comment: are you sure you are compiling the danish locale as well ? can you try to run in sdk /bin folder the following command  copylocale en_US da_DA, and rebuild your app.

Comment: Well - the danish locale is listed in the manifest.xml exactly as the english, german and french. But it it cannot be found in the compiled ipa, so something in the compiler is creating the problem. I tried manually adding the da-locale folder in the unpacked ipa and then repacking it, but that does not work. - finally i was given help from theRabbitFlash in the form of an edited adt.jar and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe air does not support Danish locale. the adt can simply not compile the danish name into the ipa.

I got help for a solution of @TheRabbitFlash - He built a custom adt.jar which can compile the Danish locale and now it works. If others need the same, please send me a message.

Edit: upvote the bug at adobe: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3710257

Comment: What is the error you get? or what is the exact issue.

Comment: Edited the question to describe the problem in more detail.